# Change double row formatted file to multiple row with 'Sed' or 'Awk'

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file which appends each new observation to the end of the same file containing the previous observations. Therefore the format of the file 'data.dat' is like the following:

```
# Comments
# Comments
# Comments
x01 x02
x11 x12
.
.
xN1 xN2

# Comments
# Comments
# Comments
x03 x04
x13 x14
.
.
xN3 xN4
# Comments
# Comments
# Comments
x05 x06
x15 x16
.
.
xN5 xN6
```

Essentially, data.dat for each bulk has 3 lines of comments and then two columns of data. The goal is to store the same data with the following formatting (for plotting and programming usage reasons):

```
# comments # comments # comments
# comments # comments # comments
# comments # comments # comments
x01 x02 x03 x04 x05 x06
x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 x16
.
.
xN1 xN4 xN3 xN4 xN5 xN6
```

The comments should be preserved and they are not unique. Also, luckily, the number of data points is equal for all of the observations, meaning that the number of rows is similar form the first comment to the N'th datapoint. The only constrain is that it should use bash native commands like 'awk' or 'sed'.

What is the command for doing so?

The answer by @steffen is working:

```
awk '/^#/{t=0;ah[h+0]=ah[h+0]OFS$0;h++} /^[^#]/{h=0;at[t+0]=at[t+0]OFS$0;t++} END{for (i in ah) print (ah[i]);for (i in at) print(at[i]);}' file
```

But, I'm not understanding the logic here.

Comment: No, this is not clear please provide some more useful samples of input and specially output and let us know in comments then.

Comment: The information provided in this question is not enough to come up with an answer.

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to process FASTA format?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have edited the question and hopefully, it is communicating better now, please see if it fits the bar of being re-opened?

Comment: @tripleee No, this file is the output of COMSOL multiphysics for a specific simulation

Comment: @ssemilla I have modified the question, please review it.

Comment: @Eisa, sure I have voted to reopen question, total 3 votes needed, so others could also vote for it.

Comment: Asking for code without demonstrating any attempt of your own is still unacceptable here; this should not be reopened in its current state.

Comment: @tripleee I do understand your concern, this is an old question though and the answer by steffen is doing the job, so any demonstration now would be fake. But I still don't get the logic behind it, I have further edited the question and asked for the logic behind it as well. Also, I wanted to have this question for community use, because it already fixed my problem.

Comment: You already have an accepted answer and the question seems to be scoring high enough to remain on the site. I suggest you roll back your edits and ask a new question.

Comment: @tripleee I like to do so but I have "You have reached your question limit" problem and I have to make my current questions better.

Comment: I can't directly help with that, do you have a lot of poor-quality deleted questions?

Comment: @tripleee not so many deleted ones, but my questions where direct. Like a bug in intel compiler which later Intel fixed it, stuff like that which won't get hit anymore. Or something similar in Matlab compiler. Overall, thanks for helping on this question, it now has open status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have commented, the question is unclear. You should provide output for this input:

```
$ cat file
# blah0
# blah1
# blah2
value0 value1
.
.
value2 value3
# blah3
# blah4
# blah5
value4 value5
.
.
value6 value7
# blah6
# blah7
# blah8
value8 value9
.
.
valueA valueB
```

If I had to make a guess, I'd say the logic may be so:

```
$ awk '/^#/{t=0;ah[h+0]=ah[h+0]OFS$0;h++} /^[^#]/{h=0;at[t+0]=at[t+0]OFS$0;t++} END{for (i in ah) print (ah[i]);for (i in at) print(at[i]);}' file
# blah0 # blah3 # blah6
# blah1 # blah4 # blah7
# blah2 # blah5 # blah8
value0 value1 value4 value5 value8 value9
. . .
. . .
value2 value3 value6 value7 valueA valueB
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please explain the logic a little bit?

Comment: I didn't write an exaplanation in 2018, because the question was incomplete and I didn't want to waste time for nothing (it was a guess). Without explanation, it takes more time to understand, so you should have provided more details. However, here's some explanation: There are three parts, logic for comments (`h`, don't ask, idk), for non-comments (`t`) and a final print out. Whenever there's a transition from comments to non-comments and vv, the counter for the other part is reset (`t=0`, `h=0`). And 2.: Each nth. line is concatenated with the previous nth. lines (`ah[h]=ah[h]OFS$0;h++`).

Comment: It makes more sense now. Thanks.